# HQL to retrieve the records for last 365 days

Tags: hibernate, db2, hql

In my DB2 database, I've a table where I store some employee information along with a timestamp to store the record insertion time.

By using HQL, I need to retrieve the records created for past 365 days. Can anyone help me to find a suitable HQL for the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parameterize query and give as an argument Date that is 365 days in past. Additionally you can also set time fields to zero, if all entries from the first day are preferred.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -365);
Date d = c.getTime();

List<EntityA> result = 
    em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM EntityA a where a.dateField > :param")
      .setParameter("param", d)
      .getResultList();
```

Comment: Is there an easier way if you just want to subtract one day, or is this it do you think?